# How to select multi tables with WHERE clause

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get id and name of user, who have mhId = "AAA" (mhId is a column in table User_MonHoc. In User_MonHoc, mhid + user_id are primary key).

Table User:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="entites.User" table="user" catalog="bthibernate" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="username" type="string">
        <column name="username" length="100" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="password" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="note" type="byte">
        <column name="note" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="userMonhocs" table="user_monhoc" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="user_id" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="entites.UserMonhoc" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Table User_MonHoc

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="entites.UserMonhoc" table="user_monhoc" catalog="bthibernate" optimistic-lock="version">
    <composite-id name="id" class="entites.UserMonhocId">
        <key-property name="userId" type="string">
            <column name="user_id" length="100" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="mhId" type="string">
            <column name="mh_id" length="100" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="monhoc" class="entites.Monhoc" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="mh_id" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="entites.User" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="user_id" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="thoigianDk" type="timestamp">
        <column name="thoigian_dk" length="19" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
```

I want to get id and name of user, who have mhId = "AAA" (mhId is a column in table User_MH).
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should join User and User_MH table in a SQL or HQL query. set alias to User_MH in your query o access User_MH table in where clause:

SQL :

```
SELECT tbl_user.useranme,tbl_user_mh.user_id FROM User AS tbl_user
INNER JOIN User_MH AS tbl_user_mh ON tbl_user.id=tbl_user_mh.user_id
WHERE tbl_user_mh.mhdl = 'AAA
```